# ddply and spaces in quoted variables

Tags: r, plyr

Is it possible to use spaces in ddply?

I'm using data from a spreadsheet with a lot of spaces in column names and i would like to keep those names because later on I want to export this data with the same column names as the original. There are 200+ columns and using make.names will of course give me proper names but then I lose the original column names.

However ddply doesn't seem to like spaces? Is there a workaround?

```
lev=gl(2, 3, labels=c("low", "high"))
df=data.frame(factor=lev, "fac tor"=lev, response=1:6, check.names = FALSE)

> ddply(df, c("factor"), summarize, r.avg=mean(response))
factor r.avg
1    low     2
2   high     5

> ddply(df, c("fac tor"), summarize, r.avg=mean(response))
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol
: fac tor
```

Comment: I think you meant `check.names = FALSE` up above. `TRUE` forces coercion to `fac.tor`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrapping the column names in single back ticks (`) seems to do the trick.

```
ddply(df, "`fac tor`", summarize, r.avg=mean(response))
```

You can also use column indices which may or may not be appealing depending on how big your data.frame is and your knowledge of the locations of each column beforehand.

```
ddply(df, 2, summarize, r.avg=mean(response))
```

Comment: +1 Yes, using backticks is the way to go.  FYI, plyr provides the `.()` function that allows you to specify column names without having to quote them.  So I would prefer writing `ddply(df, .(\`fac tor\`), summarize, r.avg=mean(response))`

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a regular expression to convert the spaces to some nonsense character, then convert back at the end:

```
lev=gl(2, 3, labels=c("low", "high"))
df=data.frame(factor=lev, "fac tor"=lev, response=1:6, check.names = FALSE)
colnames(df) <- gsub(" ","~",colnames(df))
```