# Running rpart over multiple subsets of a data frame

Tags: r, function, plyr, rpart

I'm creating a decision tree with the R rpart package based on x number of variables and a dataframe:

```
fit<-rpart(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=(mydataframe),
  control=rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = 0, cp=.01))
```

But instead of using the entire dataframe, I have four or five subsets of data that are factors, let's say separated out by x4.  How can I run decision trees on all of these factors at once instead of having to call subsets of the data again and again?

Based on a search of SO, it looks like either BY or ddply might be the right choice.  Here's what I've tried for ddply:

```
fit<-ddply(mydataframe, dataframe$x4, function (df)  
    rpart(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=(df), 
    control=rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = 0, cp=.01)))
```

but what I'm getting back is:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x4value' not found
```

where x4value is one of the variable values I'd like to split out by.  So I have a column of values:

x4

BucketName1

BucketName2

BucketName3

BucketName4

str(mydataframe) shows that $x4 is a : Factor w/ 8 levels and no symbols.

Additionally, I ran mydataframe = na.omit(dataframe) at the very beginning to avoid nulls.

Possible issues I've already troubleshooted:

- [Variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569079/ddply-and-spaces-in-quoted-variables)
- [Object not found referencing an object that doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463137/error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-object-not-found) (not the case since my column name exists)

  - The values of BucketName1, 2, 3, and 4 not allowed to start with a number, which I fixed.

The rpart bit runs fine when I run it manually as such:

```
mydataframe<-subset(trainData, x4=="BucketName1")

fit<-rpart(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=(mydataframe), 
    control=rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = 0, cp=.01))
```

but borks whenever I try to loop through all subsets using ddply.

Complete reproducible sample code:

```
mydataframe<-data.frame  ( x1=sample(1:10),
                           x2=sample(1:10),
                           x3=sample(1:10),
                           x4= sample(letters[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE))
str(mydataframe)

fit<-ddply(mydataframe, mydataframe$x4, function (df)
    rpart(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=(df), control=rpart.control(minsplit = 20,      minbucket = 0, cp=.01)))
```

Output:

```
str(mydataframe) 'data.frame':  20 obs. of  4 variables:  $ x1: int  1 6 8 4 7 9 3 2 10 5 ...  $ x2: int  9 4 5 8 6 3 7 10 2 1 ...  $ x3: int 2 6 5 3 1 4 9 7 10 8 ...  $ x4: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 4 4 3 2 3 4 3 3 1 3 ...
> fit<-ddply(mydataframe, mydataframe$x4, function (df) rpart(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=(df), control=rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = 0, cp=.01))) Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'd' not found
```

Comment: Please take the time to create a minimal, [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. Seems odd you getn an error about "x4value" when that doesn't appear anywhere in the code you've shared. Seems like you're leaving something important out.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've added some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do two things with your code:

1. Use `dlply` instead of `ddply`, since you want a list of rpart objects instead of a data frame of (?). `ddply` would be useful if you wanted to show predicted values of the original data, since that can be formatted into a data frame.
2. Use `.(x4)` instead of `dataframe$x4` in the `dlply`.  Using the latter will produce unpredictable results.

Additionally, in your example, you should specify a `y` value and remove the `....` from after `x4`

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I should have specified initially, but I also want to output the results with printcp(fit), but I'm getting `Error in printcp(fit) : 'x' must be an "rpart" object` for `printcp(fit)` and `plotcp(fit)`. Any hints to troubleshoot this part?

Comment: Your result is in a list.  You can do print(fit[[1]]) if you want to get the first result.  You can also make an automated `l_ply()` function to do it for you, but your function would have to save results, since the plots would overwrite each other.  You could also do something like `par(mfrow = c(2,2))` to get multiple plots per image.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an incorrect value to the `dplyr()` `.variables=` parameter. You are either supposed to pass a quoted variable name, a formula, or a character vector of variable names. Since you are passing `mydataframe$v4` that is being coerced to a character and it's looking for all the values in that column as if they were variables.

Here's what the call should look like

```
fit<-ddply(mydataframe, ~x4, function (df)
    rpart(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=(df), control=rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = 0, cp=.01)))
```

or

```
fit<-ddply(mydataframe, .(x4), function (df)
    rpart(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=(df), control=rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = 0, cp=.01)))
```

or

```
fit<-ddply(mydataframe, "x4", function (df)
    rpart(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=(df), control=rpart.control(minsplit = 20,  minbucket = 0, cp=.01)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not comfortable with plyr, you can also do this with base R functions.

```
splitData = split(mydataframe, mydataframe$x4)

getModel = function(df) {
    fit <- rpart(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+xN....,data=df, 
        control=rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = 0, cp=.01)))
    return(fit)
}

models = lapply(splitData, getModel)
```

You can also do this with dplyr instead of plyr.

```
mydataframe %>% group_by(x4) %>%
   do(model = getModel(.))
```